# Can't select images from database? (PHP)

Tags: php

I was never bofore used OOP in PHP, only in C#,C++ etc but now i want to make one website where i will use OOP.

I want to select all photos from my slike table, and show in index page.

this is engine.php file Select() function works good, but Select_Slike() does not select anything. Can you explain me please, where is error? Thank you.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
include("connect.php");
class Manage{
    public function Select(){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT naslov FROM slike");
        if($query)
        {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['slike_id'].'">'.$row['naslov'].'</option>';
            }
        }
        else{
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
    public function Select_Slike(){
        $query = mysql_query("select * from slike");
        if($query)
        {   
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo '<img src="../images/'.$row['string'].'.jpg'.'"/>';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo mysql_query();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

index.php page

```
<center>
<?php
$m = Manage;
$m->Select_Slike();
?>
</center>
```

Comment: Can we see your table schema (relevant parts anyway).

Comment: So tell us what errors you're getting. and consider $m = new Manage; instead of simply $m = Manage; and you also need a database connection

Comment: What does Select_Slike currently do?  What is it not doing?  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Putting all functions into a class is not OOP...that's just...uhm...organizing stuff?

Comment: @Till - OP has used OOP in C# and C++ before, so you'd expect them to have some understanding of OOP principles in general

Comment: MVC in PHP, as in OOP PHP, as you call it, implies a model, view, controller in which the tables are 'modeled' into classes (objects). That, kind sir, is not MVC.

Comment: talking of OOP, you really ought to be using a more modern DB library -- the `mysql_xx()` funcs are deprecated and not recommended. Use PDO instead.

Comment: @RogueCoder
I can't to upload pic from some reaseons, i don't know why.

i have table 
slike
in slike(image on eng), i have columns:
- slike_id
- naslov(title on eng)
- string
- materijal
- cena (price on eng)
- dimenzije(dimensions on eng)
- jezik (language on eng)

Comment: @Jrod

Is supposed to select image string from database, and check in directory images that string if exists show him on index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new instance by calling

```
$m = new Manage();
```

and then you can call

```
$m->Select_Slike();
```

The way you put it, I'm not sure if you'd like to have a static method.
If you want a static (class) method, you can declare it like this

```
public static function Select_Slike()
```

and then you can do

```
Manage::Select_Slike();
```

You can find out more in the php manual at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php it's explained in detail

Comment: Ok, we are very close to solution of my problem. 

Look, now i have a image logo(logo which shows that img path is wrong),

mine index.php is in 


website name/index.php


mine engine.php is in:


websitename/admin/php/engine.php


mine images dir is in:


websitename/admin/images/


I guess that i have wrong path.

Comment: the way that paths are calculated can be tricky sometimes and that's why PHP has the [server variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and various others to help you navigate your website structure. Most people use a framework nowdays, and as commentators pointed out in your question - you should consider using it as well.